# How to send data/trigger ndo_start_xmit of the ethernet network device driver?

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, linux-device-driver, ethernet

I am developing the ethernet network device driver, the steps I followed registered the device as eth1 and assigned MAC address(a0:b0,c0,d0,e0,f0), IPV4 address(192.168.10.127) to it, even can able to see the device created in /sys/class/net devices. For info, I followed all the steps to build the kernel device driver and it is generated a.ko file and loaded the driver with insmod.

When I use **ifconfig eth1 up --> device open is called,**
**ifconfig eth1 down --> device close is called,**
but when I ping it **ping -I eth1 www.google.com(something)** I can't see device transmit **ndo_start_xmit callback** is not triggered/called.

**Can someone please guide me on how to trigger ndo_start_xmit callback/transmit the data to the ethernet network device driver?**

Answer (score -1):

Invoking your driver's start_xmit routine is your responsibility, of course.  Since only you can see your driver right now :-@), that means **you** need to go down the checklist:

1. Does your struct net_dev_ops declare .ndo_start_xmit = <your_start_xmit>?
2. Does some routine in your driver act as ndo_start_xmit's caller, and can you see if you get to the point of calling it (presumably you don't)?  If not, why not?
3. Does your driver strategy require you to issue a tx interrupt?  If so, can you verify that it's getting generated and handled?
4. Does your driver execute appropriate wmb() calls to make sure that any metadata has been written/synchronised/made visible to the device so it can ***see*** that you have a packet available/queued to send and are asking for it to be sent?

If you are modeling your driver on a known-working one that was chosen to be as simple as possible, all of these points should be clear from that driver's code.  You have a much better chance of making any device driver work if you do this rather than trying to code the entire driver from scratch.

Comment: This is clearly wrong.  If it was the driver writer's responsibility to call `ndo_start_xmit` there would be no reason to register it as a callback.

Comment: It's clearly the driver writer's responsibility to have it invoked, one way or another.  I've seen it done in ways other than this in more complex drivers.

Answer (score -1):

Search the Linux source for the wrapper `netdev_start_xmit` and then begin following the code from there.

In your example you need to find the link between the L3 protocol (ICMP) and L2 (your device's output).  That lives in `ip_finish_output2`.  It will call the neighbor's `hh_output` callback.  This is set by `net/ipv4/arp.c` and will usually point to `dev_queue_xmit`, which should eventually get to your `ndo_start_xmit` callback.